# Change background colour when item is tapped

Tags: maui

Here is an observable thing:

```cs
class Thingy : ObservableObject
{

    private bool _Apply;
    public bool Apply
    {
        get { return _Apply; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _Apply, value);
            SetProperty(ref _Colour, value ? "#aaffaa" : "#FFFFFF");
        }
    }

    private string _Colour;
    public string Colour { get { return _Colour; } }
}
```

I want to show these in a list with the `.Colour` being used for the background colour and changing when tapped.

```xml
<ListView 
    ItemTapped="OnItemTapped"
        x:Name="TheListView"
        >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="10" BackgroundColor="{Binding Colour}" >
```

```cs
void OnItemTapped(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
{
    Thingyitem = args.SelectedItem as Thingy;
    item.Apply = !item.Apply;
}
```

then the grid doesn't change.

The only way I've found to get this to work is to do

```cs
TheListView.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Thingy>(_CurrentItems);
```

in `OnItemTapped` but that's really slow and causes the screen to flicker.

Is it possible to change the background colour of an item? How?

Comment: Do you want a click effect? If yes check https://medium.com/@freakyali/adding-native-click-effects-in-net-maui-dd3159a4b709

Answer (score 1):

I use this in xamarin forms.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Aqua" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

SetProperty(ref _Colour, value ? "#aaffaa" : "#FFFFFF");

to

Colour =  value == "#aaffaa"  ?? : "#FFFFFF");

Comment: That's not possible because `value` is `bool` and `Colour` is string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's you can update your Thingy class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

class Thingy : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _apply;
    public bool Apply
    {
        get { return _apply; }
        set
        {
            if (_apply != value)
            {
                _apply = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Apply));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Colour));
            }
        }
    }

    public string Colour => Apply ? "#aaffaa" : "#FFFFFF";

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}


<ListView 
    x:Name="TheListView"
    ItemTapped="OnItemTapped"
    ItemsSource="{Binding YourListOfThingies}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Padding="10" BackgroundColor="{Binding Colour}" >
                    
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

void OnItemTapped(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.SelectedItem is Thingy item)
    {
        item.Apply = !item.Apply;
    }
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
}
```

Comment: This does work, but I thought that I was already doing this because that is what inheriting from `ObservableObject` does.

Comment: I understand your point, while `ObservableObject` offers basic functionality for UI notifications, it may not cover all scenarios, such as dependencies between properties or custom logic upon changes. Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` directly in your Thingy class provides greater control over property updates and UI bindings. This ensures that the Colour property updates when Apply changes, which might not be automatically handled by ObservableObject.